# How to replace one char to get many strings in Shell?

Tags: bash, shell-script, sed

I can find many questions with answers in the other direction, but unfortunately not in the one I would like to have my replacements: I intend to **replace a char**, such as `#`, **in a string**, such as `test#asdf`, with a sequence, such as `{0..10}` **to get a sequence of strings**, in this example `test0asdf test1asdf test2asdf test3asdf test4asdf test5asdf test6asdf test7asdf test8asdf test9asdf test10asdf`.

I tried, from others:

- `echo '_#.test' | tr # {0..10}` (throws usage)
- `echo '_#.test' | sed -r  's/#/{0..10}/g'` (returns `_{0..10}.test`)
- `echo '_#.test' | sed -r 's/#/'{0..10}'/g'` (works for the first, afterwards I get `sed: can't read (...) no such file or directory`)

What is a working approach to this problem?

Edit, as I may not comment yet: I have to use `#` in the string, in which this character should be replaced, as the string passed from another program. I could first replace it with another char though.

Comment: Why not just `echo _{0..10}.test`? The way you have it, it's echoing the string first and then replacing the character which isn't going to work. You could also replace the character and then `echo`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `{0..10}` `zsh` operator (now also supported by a few other shells including `bash`) is just another form of `csh`-style brace expansion.

It is expanded *by the shell* before calling the command. The command doesn't see those `{0..10}`.

With `tr '#' {0..10}` (quoting that `#` as otherwise it's parsed by the shell as the start of a comment), `tr` ends being called with ("tr", "#", "0", "1", ..., "10") as arguments and `tr` doesn't expect that many arguments.

Here, you'd want:

```
echo '_'{0..10}'.test'
```

for `echo` to be passed "_0.test", "_1.test", ..., "_10.test" as arguments.

Or if you wanted that `#` to be translated into that `{0..10}` operator, transform it into shell code to be evaluated:

```
eval "$(echo 'echo _#.test' | sed 's/#/{0..10}/')"
```

where `eval` is being passed `echo _{0..10}.test` as arguments.

(not that I would recommend doing anything like that).

Answer (score 5):

You can *split* the string on the delimiter, capture the prefix and the suffix, then use brace expansion to generate the names:

```
str='test#asdf'
IFS='#' read -r prefix suffix <<<"$str"
names=( "$prefix"{0..10}"$suffix" )
declare -p names
```

```
declare -a names='([0]="test0asdf" [1]="test1asdf" [2]="test2asdf" [3]="test3asdf" [4]="test4asdf" [5]="test5asdf" [6]="test6asdf" [7]="test7asdf" [8]="test8asdf" [9]="test9asdf" [10]="test10asdf")'
```

Answer (score 2):

First `#` starts a comment.  So, you need to escape it with `\`.

Second, use a `for` loop.

Here is your solution:

```
for i in {1..10}
do
    echo '_#.test' | tr \# $i
done
```

`tr` unfortunately does not work for more than one character, such as when you want to substitute `#` with `10`.  You are better off using `sed` for that reason.

```
for i in {1..10}
do
    echo '_#.test' | sed "s/#/$i/"
done
```

Comment: What about the "10" result?

Answer (score 2):

Do you have to use `#`?  Maybe you could use `%d`?

```
$ for i in {1..10}; do printf "_%d.test " "$i"; done
_1.test _2.test _3.test _4.test _5.test _6.test _7.test _8.test _9.test _10.test
```

Answer (score 1):

I would do it with [parameter expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Shell-Parameter-Expansion):

```
$ var='test#asdf'
$ for i in {1..10}; do echo "${var/\#/"$i"}"; done
test1asdf
test2asdf
test3asdf
test4asdf
test5asdf
test6asdf
test7asdf
test8asdf
test9asdf
test10asdf
```

The `${parameter/pattern/string}` expansion

- takes the expansion of `$parameter` (in our case, `$var`) and
- replaces the first occurrence of *`pattern`* (the escaped `#` – `/#` has a special meaning in the context, "replace at the beginning of the string", which we want to avoid) with
- *`string`* (`"$i"` in our case)

Alternatively, you could replace the `#` with `%d` and use it as the format string for `printf`:

```
printf "${var/\#/%d}\\n" {1..10}
```